# Asciidoctor do not include the first Headline in chapter count

Tags: asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I'm setting up an asciidoctor book which is arranged as follows:

```
= Title
== Foreword & Introduction
== Chapter 1:
== Chapter 2:
...
```

The problem is that when I create the HTML/PDF, the document will be indexed as follows:

```
Title
1 Foreword & Introduction
2 Chapter 1:
3 Chapter 2:
```

So, as you can see, all chapters have an offset of "1" caused by the Foreword chapter. Is there a way to get around this, maybe excluding the Foreword from the Chapter count, or using an alphabetic counting just for the Foreword and starting the following ones from "1". Or anything else that could make the final result look better.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lucky me! I just found it when I was searching for something even different:

```
[dedication%untitled]
```